# Responsive design: complicated display table for showing photo and content in single row

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-tables

I've asked this question before (sort of), and the answer wasn't able to help me do what I'm trying to do.  After working on this website more, and countless hours trying to figure out the solution to this (I'm not even entirely sure it can be done), I'm back trying to figure this out.  It's the centerpiece for the home page, so it's kind of important it works the way I want, visually.

The problem:
I have two "modules" (displayed as table cells) in a container (displayed as a table).  I have created this [***jsfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/dWugB/118/) as a way to show how the model will interact with a landscape image and portrait image.  I'll go ahead and list the requirements.

- The content container should have a **minimum** width of 30% - 30px (10px padding and a border of 20px on the right) of the container.
- If the photo isn't big enough to take up 70% of the container, the content container width should grow and photo container width shrink.
- The height of the content container (which will essentially be a news/blog post) should never be taller or shorter than the image.  If the contents overflow, they should be scrollable.
- To prevent this block from being absolutely super tall, it shouldn't have a height over 1000px (I'm think maybe setting the image max-height would be the way to say this.

I feel like I've been all over the internet trying to figure out how to do this, and I have had no luck.

Below is mark-up and styling:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class = "content">
        <h5>
            blah
        </h5>
    </div>
    <div class = "image">
        <img src="http://www.blah.com/blah.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

#container {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #cc0000;
}
#container .content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-width: calc(30% -40px);
    border-right: 20px solid #383838;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow:scroll;
}

#container .image {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #ccc;
    max-height: 100%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.  What part of your code doesn't work?  Can you provide a graphic example of what you expect it to do?

Comment: I don't see any photo in your example. Can you make a paint of what you exactly want?

Comment: check the jsfiddle, I accidentally didn't save it.  If it still doesn't make sense, I'd be happy to explain in more detail.